# Health Management Reimbursement Accounts (HMRAs / HMAs)

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, hsa, savings-account, fsa

I recently heard about an interesting alternative to HSAs called "Health Matching Account Services" ("HMRAs"/"HMAs"). However, most of what I can find out about them is on the very website of their unique marketer, [nationalprosperity.com](http://www.nationalprosperity.com/). (There is also one article in [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/johngoodman/2017/05/17/a-new-approach-to-high-deductibles/#17fd93ac72cc).)

1) Can someone explain what these are and how they work to me in simple terms?

2) For whom, if anyone, are these accounts a good idea? (I am considering starting the account as an individual.)

3) Are there risks involved, given their apparent newness and unfamiliarity? Are there perhaps other downsides accompanying their unusual profitability?